# How can I perform client side sorting with Ext JS 4?

Tags: sorting, extjs4, client-side, gridpanel

I have a `Grid Panel` that loads about 200 records from the server.  I can implement a paging bar just fine, so that I load 10 records per page.  However, the problem is that when our users click a column (such as Customer) to sort, it only sorts the local 10 rows.

When they go to the next page, it isn't sorted and they get confused.  I thought about pulling all 200 records down at once and try paging that way.  I know it's not the best way but I can't think of another solution.

PLUS, our remote sorting routine can't really be changed due to timing constraints.  It only handles `offset` and `limit`.  So I can easily bring all 200 down but I can't alter how the columns are sorted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way you are doing it makes the most sense (since you can't sort the 200 results in place, although I'm not 100% on why). You just need to implement a way to remember the sorting option the user chose, and carry this forward to the next page.

EDIT: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/data has a section on sorting. Also take a peek at http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.SortTypes.

Comment: Well, our server side code does not allow sorting by column (unfortunately) and we can't change it anytime soon.  So a grid might have 10-15 columns.  We just don't want to show all 200 records at once.  So when you click on "Next Page" you would be pulling locally instead of remotely.  If that makes sense.

Comment: Oh, I was confused by "So I can easily bring all 200 down but I can't alter how the columns are sorted" I thought you meant once you have the list size 200 client-side, it's immutable.

Comment: Sorry, yes I meant I can't alter how the `server` side columns are sorted.  Basically, the search (server side) is etched in stone for a long while.  So I will only be able to sort client-side.